# Spring Batch: @Value is null when other annotations are not

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a Java/Spring application that connects to a Mongo database. The application uses Spring annotations throughout. I have a base database class that looks like this:

```
public abstract class MongoDataBase {

@Value("${db.url}")
private String DB_URL;
@Value("${db.index}")
private String DB_INDEX;

public DBCollection createConnection() {
    try {
        MongoURI mongoURI = new MongoURI(DB_URL);
        DB db = mongoURI.connectDB();
        db.authenticate(mongoURI.getUsername(), mongoURI.getPassword());
        return db.getCollection(DB_INDEX);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

This works perfectly when I connect through the MVC way (@Controller class is autowired to an @Service class which is autowired to another @Service class (my DAO) which in turn loads the connection like this:

```
 DBCollection coll = createConnection();
```

However, when I attempt to access the database from a Spring Batch job, the @Value's in the base class are null. The rest of the annotations work however (@Autowired). I have a spring batch XML which calls the following runMeJob:

```
@Component
public class RunMeJob extends QuartzJobBean {

private RunMeTask runMeTask;

public void setRunMeTask(RunMeTask runMeTask) {
    this.runMeTask = runMeTask;
}

protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context)
        throws JobExecutionException {
    runMeTask.batchRunner();
}
}
```

This in turn calls the runMeTask:

```
@Component
public class RunMeTask {

@Autowired
private AccountService accountService;
@Autowired
private ScanService scanService;

public void batchRunner() {
    JSONArray accounts = accountService.getAllAccounts();
    HashSet<String> uniqueAccounts
            = accountService.getAccountProp(accounts, "name");
}
}
```

From here the autowired accountService, connects to the base database class and the @Value is null. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out- super simple. I had the property file mapped in the mvc-dispatcher-servlet by:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:prop.properties" />
```

But did not have this in my Spring batch xml file. Not sure why the mvc-dispatcher isn't picked up when the batch job runs though?